# How to map Grafana legend values to ec2 instance names

Tags: grafana, amazon-cloudwatch, grafana-variable

I realize there have been questions asked about this but I wanted to check that I'm not missing anything. We have hundreds of ec2 instances' cpu usage coming to a Grafana dashboard and I'm trying to update the legend to show the instance name instead of the id. I can get the instance name in a variable which is part of the frustration as I feel that I'm close.

I have tried with Grafana's dynamic labels and overwrites but due to the sheer number of instances displayed I can't write overwrites for all of them. The labels only appear to support dimensions and not the metadata like the name. Any help or pointers would be appreciated, I've scoured all over and still not finding what I need if its even possible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.